# 2011 Macbook Air connects to WiFi but can't get Internet

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, high-sierra, internet

This 2011 MBA is updated to High Sierra.  I have tried to connect to 5 different WiFi networks but in all cases, the MBA can connect to local network but no Internet.

All 5 of these networks are professionally configured in hotels.

Running Diagnostics seems to say everything is ok.  Also, at the same time I can connect to the same networks with another Macbook Air (2013, Mojave) and two different iPhones (8 and 6s) with no problems.

If I turn on Personal Hotspot in either of the two iPhones, the 2011 MBA obtains Internet no problem and gives a fast connection.

The 2011 MBA used to work fine on wifi with no problems.  It may be that updating the OS has somehow caused a problem, but I'm not the primary user of the 2011 machine and am not sure if the problem appeared with HS or was there before.

Does anyone have any suggestions to troubleshoot a WiFi connection that doesn't get to the internet?

Comment: what is your router ? did you reset it ?

Comment: All 5 of these networks are professionally configured in hotels and aren't available to reset.  I have been traveling for some time.   But surely the same behavior across multiple networks indicates the 2011 MBA is somehow the problem.  Especially since other devices can connect no the same networks at the same time with no problem.

Comment: open your browser on the mac, then type cnn.com in the web address

Comment: I would say someone has played around with your default route or DNS entries on your wifi adapter. Go to network settings and check both DNS and static routes for your wifi adapter, there is anything in there delete it.

Comment: When you say “no Internet”, what exactly do you mean? Have you tried `ping 8.8.8.8`?

Comment: Connecting to WiFi is not the same as connecting to the network.  You may be *associated* to the AP, but you don't have an IP.  This could be due to the public WiFi being oversubscribed and they ran out of leases.  First thing to check is the IP address of your adapter.